# If editable div have no text than set placeholder

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am try to make editable div with placeholder.But i want when no text in this div than automatically placeholder set.

Actually i am using `contentEditable='true';` this element On div.And i am handle placeholder with jQuery to this function. 
        `

```
     $('div').on('activate',
        function() {
       $(this).empty();
       var range, sel;
     if ( (sel = document.selection) && document.body.createTextRange){
    range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(this);
    range.select();} });    


    $('div').focus(function() {
    if (this.hasChildNodes() && document.createRange && window.getSelection) {

   $(this).empty();
    var range, sel;
    range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(this);
    sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
}});
```

`

Comment: I should post some code, what is your markup? What do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="editDiv">Placeholer</div>
```

jQuery

```
var placeholder = "Placeholder"; //Change this to your placeholder text
$("#editDiv").focus(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == placeholder) {
        $(this).text("");
    }
}).focusout(function() {
    if (!$(this).text().length) {
        $(this).text(placeholder);
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not right thing not suit of my requirement.

Answer (score 10):

you coud try to use CSS with pseudo  `:empty` and `:before` and data attributes.
http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/hzLIE

```
div:empty:before {
  content:attr(data-placeholder);
  color:gray
}
```

```
<div  contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="You can insert & edit content here."></div>
```

It should work in a few browser

Answer (score 0):

Your question was very vague but I'm gonna try my best to give you some kind of serviceable solution:

HTML:

```
<div id="editableDiv">
    <textarea id="editText" placeholder="This is my placeholder"></textarea>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#editableDiv {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}

#editText {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Sorry if its not what you're looking for but that's the best I can do with the amount of information given.

http://jsfiddle.net/LB7cp/

Answer (score -3):

It isn't very clear in the wording of the question, but it sounds like you want to make a [text area](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp).

Comment: I don't want text-area i know about that.