# Is it possible to add placeholder in div tag

Tags: html, css

I would like to display some text to the user when my `div` element is empty.

I have tried adding a [placeholder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-placeholder) attribute to my `div` but the text is not being displayed.

```
<div placeholder="Enter the text"> </div>
```

How can I display a message when my `div` element is empty?

Comment: Why would you want to show a placeholder? What exactly do you mean by placeholder?

Comment: In fact, if you want something to show in the div, you got the place the content within the tags: <div>Hello</div>.

Comment: why are you use placeholder for div?you can use input type or textarea and then use placeholder.

Comment: question already exists : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753819/if-editable-div-have-no-text-than-set-placeholder/17754905

Answer (score 201, accepted):

There are lot of options using javascript, but if you want to do it in css. Try this:

```css
[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before {
  content: attr(data-text)
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable=true data-text="Enter text here"></div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/d3975/1/)

Comment: That's pretty beautiful! I've never seen this solved so neatly. May i ask about compatibility? Cause i'd like to use that as well :)

Comment: @In Lak'esh It works in all browsers accept the fact that if your using CSS2 browsers then instead of `data-text` you need to use `title`..

Comment: Notice that this won't work if there is any character or white-space between the opening and the closing div tags.

Comment: Joke_Sense, I have "<div><br></div>" in my contenteditable div. How can I make it display placeholder?

Comment: Simply magnificient, thank you. May I add that by removing `:not(:focus)` from the css selector, it actually behaves like an authentic placeholder.

Comment: This is a great solution. I found that by changing :before to :after allowed it to work in IE and Edge also, as the cursor was positioned after the placeholder text otherwise.

Comment: This changes the design of the div entirely. It made my div bend downwards and I couldnt get it to go back up... *sadface*

Comment: Also mind the attribute case of the built html tag

Answer (score 39):

i have already answered to such a question here with this test : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/hzLIE

```
div:empty:before {
  content:attr(data-placeholder);
  color:gray
}
```

see [If editable div have no text than set placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753819/if-editable-div-have-no-text-than-set-placeholder/17754905#17754905)

Comment: This is the right answer! It behaves like normal placeholder and works even in 2021, Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

This can also be achieved without the use of the [contentEditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable) attribute, using plain CSS.

Using the [:empty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) pseudo-class along with the [::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) pseudo-element you can add a placeholder to an empty element.

The following example provides a fallback placeholder for `div` elements that do not have a `data-placeholder` attribute defined.

Example:

```css
div:empty::before {
  color: grey;
}
div[data-placeholder]:not([data-placeholder=""]):empty::before {
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
}
div:empty::before {
  content: 'fallback placeholder';
}
```

```html
<div data-placeholder='data- placeholder'></div>
<br>
<div></div>
```

Comment: best answer so far

Answer (score 2):

Assuming what you really want to do is to have the user input some text and show him some placeholder in the input field, this is what you can use:

```
<input type="text" value="Enter the text" onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter the text'){this.value='';}" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Enter the text';}" />
```

Of course you can wrap the input in a div.

```
<div><input [...] /></div>
```

You can see this in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ftpdm/)

Answer (score 1):

This ensures a cursor in an empty div

```css
[contentEditable="true"]:empty:not(:focus):before {
    content: attr(data-placeholder);
}

[contentEditable="true"]:empty:focus:before {
    content: " ";
}
```