# Unable to validate HTML5 when using placeholder in div

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I've been contributing to a WYSIWYG text editor that was made using HTML5 and jQuery. While doing some of my research I've been seeing a lot of people use the placeholder attribute in a div. However, this does not follow the specification and I end up with the following error when I try to validate my HTML.

> Attribute “placeholder” not allowed on element “div” at this point.

Is there a better way to do this so that my HTML will validate and I still end up with a placeholder?

Comment: If it works for your purposes, don’t worry about HTML validity. It’s meant to catch mistakes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300138/is-it-possible-to-add-placeholder-in-div-tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Juantxo Cruz's link I was able to fix my issue by using CSS as shown below:

**HTML**

```
<div contentEditable=true data-placeholder="Sample text"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before {
content:attr(data-placeholder)
}
```