# How to prevent that a line break gets inserted into an empty editable div (in Firefox)?

Tags: css, firefox

I try to give an editable `div` a placeholder as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20300212/402322).

The code works in Chrome but in Firefox it works only partially. In Firefox initially the `div` is empty and the placeholder is shown. When I enter some text the placeholder disappears. Fine so far. But when I remove all text I have entered and remove the focus, the placeholder does not come back, although the `div` should be empty.

If I inspect the element, I can see that as soon as I remove the last character a `<br>` node gets inserted into the `div`. This is the reason why it is not empty.

How can I avoid, that the `<br>` gets inserted into an empty editable `div`?

```css
[contenteditable="true"] {
  background-color: yellow;
}

[contenteditable="true"]:empty:not(:focus)::before{
  content:attr(data-text);
  color: gray;
}

[contenteditable="true"]::before{
  content: '\200b';
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" data-text="placeholder" size="10"></div>
```

Comment: It's coming back here.

Comment: @MrGeek I am using Firefox. Do you use Chrome?

Comment: Yes, I use Chrome.

Comment: @MrGeek I added the [`firefox`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox) tag as it seems to be a Firefox specific problem.

Comment: Didn't see it, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround I use now an observer in Firefox. But I am still interested how to avoid it.

```
(function () {
  if (/firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))
  {
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
      mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if (mutation.target.innerHTML == '<br>') {
          mutation.target.innerHTML = '';
        }
      });
    });

    document.querySelectorAll('[contenteditable="true"]').forEach(function(div) {
      observer.observe(div, { childList: true });
    });
  }
})();
```

Comment: Did you find a better solution for this problem?  If not, too bad this is the best solution, but I'm copy/pasting it. Thanks