# Stop pasting html style in a contenteditable div only paste the plain text

Tags: javascript, css

I am using a contenteditable div, when I tried to paste something with style, it was suppose to only copy the plain text, but it got the style as well, does anyone know how to force it to convert to plain text when I paste it or anyone has a better solution

Here is my code:

```
    <div contenteditable="true">   
      This text can be edited by the user. 
    </div>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use an `<input>` or `<textarea>` for this? The `contenteditable="true"` on a non-traditional input is terrible for accessibility and its cross-browser support isn't that great either. Inputs and TextAreas are plenty customizable.

Comment: Indeed...unable to reproduce. Are you sure you pasted *text* it looks like you pasted a whole bunch of HTML

Comment: @n8jadams Because I want it can be auto resized based on the length of content, I don’t want to use scroll bar. Plus, I need to vertically center the placeholder and text. Have tried both ways, maybe contentditable will be easier.

Comment: @Paulie_D you clearly did not paste rich text if you could not reproduce. When you copy rich text or html and paste it into a contenteditable, the styles and elements are added.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

When you paste in rich content, it will be displayed as rich content. So you would need to capture the paste event, prevent the default action, and read the text from the clipboard.

```js
var ce = document.querySelector('[contenteditable]')
ce.addEventListener('paste', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var text = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')
  document.execCommand('insertText', false, text)
})
```

```css
  [contenteditable] {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
  }
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true"></div>

<div>
  <h1>Test content</h1>
  <p style="color:red">Copy <em>this</em> <u>underlined</u></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it should be `insertHTML` instead of `insertText`, since the later will convert new-lines into divs.

Comment: document.execCommand is deprecated. Is it okay to use it?

Comment: @TàiHatranduc I think you are answering your own question as you ask it :)

Comment: My question is why "execCommand" is being used in these examples, why not just grab that text and set the text value to be what was in the clipboard (after stripping out formatting)... or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @Sergey Because the text may not be the entire innerHTML of the element. They may be pasting content between two words. They may have selected a paragraph and are pasting to replace it. This takes care out that. You can do it without the command, but it is a lot of code. The Other answer just replaces the content, but you can see the comment says why it does not work correctly

Answer (score 8):

You can set the [`contenteditable` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable) value to `plaintext-only` like this:

```html
<div contentEditable="plaintext-only"></div>
```

> indicates that the element's raw text is editable, but rich text formatting is disabled

Well [supported most browsers but Firefox](https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_global_attributes_contenteditable_plaintext-only)

Comment: It works perfectly without any JS. Best answer! Thanks!

Comment: At the time of writing this comment, it does not work in Firefox

Answer (score 5):

There is a non-standard [`user-modify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-modify) CSS property which is supported by [WebKit-based browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_user-modify_read-write-plaintext-only):

```
-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
```

This eliminates the need to use deprecated `execCommand` API or error-prone steps to position caret correctly.

```css
[contenteditable] {
  -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
}
```

```html
<div><p style="color:red">Copy <em>this</em> <u>styled</u> text</p></div>
<div contenteditable="true">into this editable element</div>
```

There is one strange behavior: copy-and-paste text selected via double-click may introduce extra leading and/or trailing whitespaces (on macOS at least).

---

To support non-WebKit browsers, you still need to listen to `paste` event, such as:

```
someEditableElement.addEventListener("paste", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const text = e.clipboardData ? e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain") : "";

  if (document.queryCommandSupported?.("insertText")) {
    return document.execCommand("insertText", false, text);
  }

  const selection = document.getSelection();
  if (!selection) return;
  const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  range.deleteContents();
  range.insertNode(new Text(text));
  range.collapse(); // select nothing
  selection.removeAllRanges(); // position caret after inserted text
  selection.addRange(range); // show caret
});
```

There are differences between these two approaches. Use your discretion.

Comment: Thanks! Second approach works fine in React (NextJS). I have juste removed the execComand block! Just be carefull with "Text" if you have a component with same name!

Answer (score 3):

You can intercept the "paste" event and replace the content of the target.

```js
/* Derived from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6035265/1762224 */
const onPastePlainText = (e) => {
  var pastedText = undefined;
  if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.getData) { // IE
    pastedText = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
  } else if (e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.getData) {
    pastedText = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
  }
  e.target.textContent = pastedText;
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}

document.querySelector('.ediatable-div').addEventListener('paste', onPastePlainText);
```

```css
.ediatable-div {
  border: 2px inset #EEE;
  height: 25vh;
}

/* Placeholder - Derived from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20300212/1762224 */
[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  color: #AAA;
}
```

```html
<div class="ediatable-div" contenteditable="true" data-text="Paste copied HTML here"></div>
<div>
  <p style="text-decoration:underline">Copy <strong>me</strong>, I have <em>style</em>!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work where there is already some text in the field.

Comment: Ah yes, this essentially overwrites ALL contents and replaces them with what was in the clipboard, but this needs to append to the text (including into the exact spot where the cursor is, or even more challenging [in case partial text was _selected_])

Comment: Same problem as obove: The problem ist you can not use `undo`... (CTRL+Z)

Answer (score 2):

The following solution works when there is already text in the field that is being pasted into, and it does not use the deprecated `document.execCommand()` function.

```js
// Edited from https://htmldom.dev/paste-as-plain-text/

const editable_div = document.getElementById('editable_div');

// Handle the paste event
editable_div.addEventListener('paste', function (e) {
    // Prevent the default action
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get the copied text from the clipboard
    const text = e.clipboardData
        ? (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain')
        : // For IE
        window.clipboardData
        ? window.clipboardData.getData('Text')
        : '';

    // Insert text at the current position of caret
    const range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    range.deleteContents();

    const textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
    range.insertNode(textNode);
    range.selectNodeContents(textNode);
    range.collapse(false);

    const selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
});
```

```html
<div id="editable_div" contenteditable="true">
    You can only paste plain text into me!
</div>
```

Comment: The problem ist you can not use `undo`... (CTRL+Z)

Answer (score 0):

When contenteditable elements might be dynamically added to the DOM, it is useful to have a document-level handler that, once there, will detect future instances as well as existing ones.

```
// 1. Paste plain text only into contenteditable elements
document.addEventListener("paste", function (e) {
    if (e.target.isContentEditable) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var text = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')
        document.execCommand('insertText', false, text)
    }
});

// 2. Prevent any paste into contenteditable elements
document.addEventListener("paste", function (e) {
    if (e.target.isContentEditable) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```